# Having trouble with border-spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a website re vamp, and am having a little bit of trouble with spacing a group of divs. The divs are actually pretty much pertfectly spaced & positioned, the issue is that they are using the "border-spacing" property. If you look at the screeshot attached, you can see the the "border-spacing" is causing the divs to be spaced on both sides, causing them to be indented a little bit on the left and right out of line with the rest of the page (see the red block above the div's, they are indented a little bit from the border-spacing). I tried replacing the border-spacing with margin-right, but it didn't do anything at all. Any advice on how to just set spacing in between the divs?

[image]

```css
    .community .atable {
     display: table;
     border-collapse: separate;
     border: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     outline: none;
     border-spacing: 1.5em;
     width: 100%;
     table-layout: fixed;
    }
    .community .atable .arow {
     display: table-row;
    }
    .community .atable .acell {
     display: table-cell;
     height: 100%;
     width: 33%;
     border-radius: 3px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     background-color: #fff;
     outline: none;
     vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .community .atable .acell .contentbox {
     position: relative;
    }
    .community .atable .acell .contentbox .pad {
     padding: 2%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="community">
        <div class="wrap">
    
        <div class="atable">
        <div class="acell">
        <div class="contentbox">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/CityofNewportRI" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/gov-img.jpg" alt="Facebook" /><span class="covered">Government Call-to-Action here.</span></a>
        </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="acell">
        <div class="contentbox">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQEXfLzrNpxe7AZme3dTP0w" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/problem-img.jpg" alt="Youtube" /><span class="covered">Report a Problem.</span></a>
        </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="acell">
        <div class="contentbox">
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/projects/photos"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/howdoi-img.jpg" alt="Photo Project" /><span class="covered">How Do I ______? Call-to-Action here.</span></a>
        </div>
        </div>
    
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I don't see `.arow` (for table rows) being used in your HTML at all.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a CSS grid framework?

Comment: I'm working on a website that was already completed. just modifying sections of it. For future reference, what is a really good CSS grid framework?

Comment: My top three are [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) and [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/grid.html). All of those come with more than just a grid. You don't have to use the extras if you don't want. Skeleton is the minimalist of the three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to apply a negative left and right margin to the `display:table` element, to compensate for the border-spacing applied to those sides. You'll also need to increase the width accordingly (`calc` is supported in IE9 and up).

```
.community .atable {
    margin-left: -1.5em;
    margin-right: -1.5em;
    width: calc(100% + 3em);
```

That said, I would encourage you to practice using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as the more forward-looking solution.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `display:table` and `border-spacing`, try using `display:flex` and `justify-content:space-between`. You'll also need to change the `width` of the child elements, subtracting the value you were using for the `border-spacing`. You may need to prefix the [flexbox properties](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and [`calc` value](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), depending on the browsers you want to support.

```css
    .community .atable {
     display: flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
     border: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     outline: none;
     width: 100%;
    }
    .community .atable .arow {
     display: table-row;
    }
    .community .atable .acell {
     display: table-cell;
     height: 100%;
     width: calc(33% - 1.5em);
     border-radius: 3px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     background-color: #fff;
     outline: none;
     vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .community .atable .acell .contentbox {
     position: relative;
    }
    .community .atable .acell .contentbox .pad {
     padding: 2%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="community">
        <div class="wrap">
    
        <div class="atable">
        <div class="acell">
        <div class="contentbox">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/CityofNewportRI" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/gov-img.jpg" alt="Facebook" /><span class="covered">Government Call-to-Action here.</span></a>
        </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="acell">
        <div class="contentbox">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQEXfLzrNpxe7AZme3dTP0w" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/problem-img.jpg" alt="Youtube" /><span class="covered">Report a Problem.</span></a>
        </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="acell">
        <div class="contentbox">
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/projects/photos"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/howdoi-img.jpg" alt="Photo Project" /><span class="covered">How Do I ______? Call-to-Action here.</span></a>
        </div>
        </div>
    
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You should at least mention which browsers don't support flexbox yet.

Comment: Ah, now, would you give me a minute to grab the relevant links from caniuse.com! ;) Answer updated.

Comment: This worked, the reason I didn't try flexbox is because we don't really like to use it yet at the company I work for. It is still fairly new and only supported by a number of browsers. I am going to go with it for now, but if there is any other way that doesn't involve flexbox that would be great!

Comment: Flexbox works in everything from IE10 on up, if you include the proper prefixes and translate it for the "tweener" syntax IE10 supports. Run your code through [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) and it'll add those for you.